# ‘Unprecedented achievement’: who received the first billion COVID vaccinations?

Tags: word-usage

The use of "who" appears to be odd to me. According to the content, it seems to mean "the people around the world."  What does "who" mean exactly?

> **‘Unprecedented achievement’: who received the first billion COVID vaccinations?**
> It took just four months to reach this global milestone, and hitting to the two-billion mark could happen even faster, say scientists.
> The world has reached the milestone of administering one billion doses of COVID-19 vaccines, just four months after the World Health Organization (WHO) approved the first vaccine for emergency use, and roll-outs began in countries such as the United States and the United Kingdom. The speed at which they have been administered is remarkable, but unequal distribution of the vaccinations highlights global disparities, say researchers.

> Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01136-2)

Comment: Note the question mark. 'Who' here is used interrogatively. Which people, the question asks, received the first billion COVID vaccinations?

Comment: I've thought that too. But the question is tricky - so far the US has vaccinated more people than any other countries. But the US population is only 331 millions and UK about 68 millions... so even if the US vaccinates 100% its people (herd immunity doesn't need that, 60 - 70% is sufficient to block the transmission), it can never achieve one billion and would be excluded.

Comment: “Global milestone” should make it clear.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is, because you seem to understand that "who" can refer to people around the world.  The question "Who received the first billion COVID vaccinations?" isn't asking "Was it the US, or the UK?"  It's just asking "who, of all the people around the world, were the ones who got the vaccine?"

Answer (score 1):

Since the vaccine requires two doses to be effective, it means it's around half as many people that have been vaccinated around the world.

From the article:

> As of 27 April, 1.06 billion doses had been given to 570 million people, which means that about 7.3% of the world’s population of 7.79 billion have received at least one dose.